Unexplained conclusion in proof of Lebesgue's Integrability Criterion from McGill lecture notes
''$\textbf{Theorem (Lebesgue's Integrability Criterion).}$ A bounded function on $[a, b]$ is Riemann integrable if and only if the points of discontinuity of $f$ form a set $D$ of measure zero. $\hspace{120cm}$ $\textbf{Proof.}$  ($\Rightarrow$) Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given and let $D_i$ be the set of points $x$ with $\omega_f(x) \geq \frac{\epsilon}{2^i}$. Let $P$ be the partition ${a = x_0 < x_1 < \cdots < x_n = b}$ of $[a, b]$ with
$$U(P, f) - L(P, f) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} (M_k - m_k) \Delta x_k < \frac{\epsilon}{4^i}.$$
If $x \in D_i \cap (x_{k-1}, x_k)$, there is an $r > 0$ such that $N_r(x) \subset (x_{k-1}, x_k)$ so that
$$
\frac{\epsilon}{2^{i}} \leq \omega_f(x) \leq \Omega_f(N_r(x)) = M_k - m_k.
$$
If $T$ is the set of these $k$ with $D_i \cap (x_{k-1}, x_k) \neq \emptyset $, it follows that
$$
\frac{\epsilon}{2^{i}} \sum_{k \in T} \Delta x_k \leq \sum_{k=1}^{n} (M_k - m_k) \Delta x_k < \frac{\epsilon}{4^i}.
$$
Hence $\sum_{k \in T} [x_k - x_{k-1}] < \frac{\epsilon}{2^i}$ and $D_i \subset \bigcup_{k \in T} [x_{k-1}, x_k]$. This shows that each $D_i$ is contained in the union of a finite number of intervals, the sum of whose lengths is less than $\frac{\epsilon}{2^i}$. Since $D = \bigcup D_i$, it follows that $D$ is of measure zero."


How come does the author deduce that from:
$$\frac{\epsilon}{2^i}\sum\limits_{k \in T}\Delta x_k < \frac{\epsilon}{4^i}$$
We would get:
$$\sum\limits_{k \in T}\Delta x_k < \frac{\epsilon}{2^i}$$
It is clear that from the first inequality we would get:
$$\sum\limits_{k \in T}\Delta x_k < \frac{1}{2^i}$$
However, if we suppose his deduction to be true, then we would need:
$$\forall \ \epsilon > 0 : \frac{\epsilon}{2^i} < \frac{1}{2^i} \text{        or        } \frac{\epsilon}{2^i} > \frac{1}{2^i}$$
Since both of them do not hold, then I would assume the author has simply made an error here. It is easily fixed once we replace:
$$ \omega_f(x) \geq \frac{\epsilon}{2^i} $$
with:
$$ \omega_f(x) \geq \frac{1}{2^i} $$
Please let me know if I am missing something.
The excerpt is taken from the following lecture: https://www.math.mcgill.ca/labute/courses/255w03/L10.pdf

Please don't use images of math or text.  Instead, transcribe it using Mathjax.  Also we require you to provide a proper reference for the source of the text you are copying/quoting.

Please improve the title.  A title should give people more of an idea of what to expect will be in the question and its topic.

Are you still editing the post?

I have taken the liberty to make the title more specific. Feel free to revert or improve the change if you don't like it!

It's fine. Thank you for the title!

That looks like an error in the definition of $D_i$. If one defines $D_i$ as the set of all $x$ with $\omega_f(x) \geq 1/2^i$ then $D = \bigcup_i D_i$ still holds, and we have
$$
\frac{1}{2^{i}} \sum_{k \in T} \Delta x_k \leq \sum_{k=1}^{n} (M_k - m_k) \Delta x_k < \frac{\epsilon}{4^i}.
$$
which now implies $\sum_{k \in T} [x_k - x_{k-1}] < \frac{\epsilon}{2^i}$, so that the (outer) Lebesgue measure of $D_i$ is less than $\epsilon /2^i$, and that of $D$ is less than $\epsilon$. This holds for all $\epsilon > 0$, so that $D$ is measurable with measure zero.
